# Relationship of Flux with Energy

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, experimental-physics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Electric Flux seems an arbitrarily defined construct that has no solid anchoring in fundamental physical quantities, and which is only hanging around for historical reasons.

**What is it measuring exactly?**

Please do not define it in terms of lines of forces. They are just a visualizing aid. There are no laws or conservation principles for these lines.

We also know that fields do not "flow".

**Does flux even has a remote connection with some fundamental physical property like energy etc**.

or

**What electric flux means for an experimenter.**

Answer (score 0):

Electric flux is not related to energy. The energy density of an electric field at each point is proportional to $\vec{E}^2$, which has nothing to do with flux.

On the other hand, the electric flux through any closed surface directly measures the electric charge inside, through [Gauss’ Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law). This is the integral form of the Maxwell equation that relates the divergence of the electric field at each point to the charge density at that point.

The flux of a vector field is important anytime the divergence of that vector field is important, because of the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). Flux is not a concept that is “only hanging around for historical purposes”. Instead it is an extremely useful mathematical construct that allows certain volume integrals to be turned into surface integrals. You should consider it remarkable that knowing what is happening on the *boundary* of a volume tells you something about what is happening *inside*.